# Setting up Scala project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is there a standard in place for setting up a Scala project where the `build.sbt` is contained in a subdirectory?

I've cloned https://github.com/lightbend/cloudflow and opened it in IntelliJ, here is the structure:

[image]

Can see core contains `build.sbt`.

If I open the project `core` in a new project window then IntelliJ will recognise the Scala project.

How to compile the Scala project `core` while keeping the other folders available within the IntelliJ window?

Comment: What are you trying to do with their github repo? Is there a reason you can't import their libraries into your own project? You cloned a massive repository with multiple projects

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer I cloned the repo to compile and run the unit tests of Cloudflow to increase my understanding of how Cloudflow works. The project 'core' contains 1 build.sbt and is the lowest level of granularity for a project, the Cloudflow projects within core do not contain build.sbt and so cannot be compiled independently.

Comment: Did you import the project as an SBT project? It should suffice to open Intellij with the build.sbt under the root directory (so root would be core)

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer yes, imported as an sbt, it compiles, thanks

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
If you do want to play around with the project, it should suffice to either import an SBT project and select core as the root. Intellij should also detect the `build.sbt` if you open core as the root.

---

Here is the [SBT Reference Manual](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Basic-Def.html)

Traditionally, `build.sbt` will be at the root of the project.

If you are looking to use their libraries, you should import them in your sbt file, you shouldn't clone the repo unless you intend to modify or fork their repo.

For importing libraries into your project take a look at the [Maven Repository for Cloudflow](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lightbend.cloudflow), select the project(s), click on the version you want, and select the SBT tab. Just copy and paste those dependencies into your `build.sbt`. Once you build the project with SBT, you should have all those packages available to you.

So in `[ProjectRoot]/build.sbt` something along the lines of

```scala
val scalaVersion = "2.13.4"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Your_Project_Name",
    scalaVersion := scalaVersion,
    libraryDependencies += "com.lightbend.cloudflow" %% "cloudflow-streamlets" % "2.0.26-RC12",
        // Either sequentially
    libraryDependencies += "com.lightbend.cloudflow" %% "cloudflow-akka" % "2.0.26-RC12",
        // Or as a sequence (note that you can have a trailing comma for these)
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "com.lightbend.cloudflow" %% "cloudflow-blueprint" % "2.0.26-RC12",
        "com.lightbend.cloudflow" %% "cloudflow-flink" % "2.0.26-RC12", // No next elemenet
    )
        // Or combo using both like above, just don't forget the commas in between
  )
```